# Javascript documentation clarification

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

I am returning to Javascript development after many years of not doing it. I am running visual studio code on a mac. I am having trouble understanding the tool tip documentation provided for me in visual studio code.

Could some one please clarify?

Example 1:

```
const numbers = [1,5,3,8];
let val;
val = numbers.sort(
```

When I am hoovering over the sort function I get this:
[image]

As far as I can tell this tells me that:

- (method) -> This is a method
- Array -> This is an array
- -> The types in the array are numbers?
- sort -> The name of the method
- compareFn?: (a: number, b: number) -> The input parameter is a function(a,b)
- => number -> The return type must be a number? (Not sure about the =>)
- number[] -> The method returns an array

Is this correct?

Example 2:

```
const numbers = [1,5,3,8];
let val;
val = numbers.find(
```

Tool tip:
[image]

I am not sure what this means. 
To be clear, looking at this [reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) I understand how to use the find method but I don't understand the documentation. Also the reference displays the syntax as this:

```
arr.find(callback[, thisArg])
```

Comment: Your question is too broad, you made a lot of questions in just one. Please, be more specific, what you want to know more specifically?

Comment: Yes, you understood it correctly.

Comment: I don't understand the find example I wrote and the link provided don't answer my question.